# Need to slide 2 objects at different speeds in one slide with one button - Using "Anything Slider"

Tags: jquery, slider, anythingslider

I'm trying to modify the "Anything Slider" by Chris Coyer so that a nested div in the slide list item will slide off the page before the slide background.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I've only really used jQuery plugins and modified their styles, not the functionality.

here's a link to what I'm working on:
http://malleckdesignco.com/test

Thanks! Let me know if I can be more specific. I've searched and searched but haven't found an answer. Thanks!!

Joe

Comment: You want the text span to slide off first?

Comment: YES!! I want the text to slide then the large background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the FX extension... see  [Demo 2](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/demos.htm)